# Save many row in core data

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I read very be careful the instruction how to save many rows into a table by core data but it's worked wrong.The value which saved is always the seconds, and have two values. Please help me to find out the mistake into my code:

```
    -(void)saveDataToLocal{

    NSManagedObject *newPref;
    newPref = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Company" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [newPref setValue:@"SiliconPrime" forKey:@"name"];
    [newPref setValue:@"Software company at VietNam" forKey:@"descreption"];
    [newPref setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:3] forKey:@"rating"];
    //
    newPref = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Company" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [newPref setValue:@"Microsoft" forKey:@"name"];
    [newPref setValue:@"USA Company" forKey:@"descreption"];
    [newPref setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:3] forKey:@"rating"];

    NSError *error;
    if (![context save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"########## Error save data %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
}
```

I called this function into the `application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`. The code wrong or do I need make any configuration into the xcdatamodeld file or somewhere else?

Comment: How are you testing what is saved? Show that code and the associated log output.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean to say that only the second object is saved? And first one is not saved? You can do either of the following

1. Call [context save:&error] before creating second context object.
2. Have two different variables for two objects.